# Releasing resources - artwork tag of TagLib file

Tags: c#, resources, tags, taglib, artwork

In my C# application I'm creating tags for mp3 files. For this I use the TagLib library/extension.

One of the tags is the artwork. I can successfully add the artwork to the mp3's tag by using:

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(path);
IPicture[] pictures = new IPicture[1];
pictures[0] = new Picture(artwork);
f.Tag.Pictures = pictures;
```

`path` is the full path to the mp3, `artwork` is the full path to the artwork.

After assigning to the Pictures tag, I use:

```
f.Save();
f.Dispose();
```

Now, it is also in my interest to move the artwork file to another location on the computer.

For this I use:

```
File.Move(pathArtOrig, pathArtNew);
```

`pathArtOrig` is the current full path of the artwork file, and `pathArtNew` is the full path of where it's going to be moved to.

The problem is the fact that I get the following error:

> IOException was unhandled. The process cannot access the file because
>   it is being used by another process.

I have simply no idea to "release" the resource of the artwork file used (it could be a .jpg file). As you can see, I tried with Dispose() above, but that's not doing the trick.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it seems I just found the error myself.

One place in my code, before tag creation, I was loading the file into a picturebox. It is stored in a Bitmap.

Now I Dispose() this Bitmap before the tag creation, and all is fine. File can now be moved.